# Calculate annual average of quarterly data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, aggregate, zoo

I have a dataframe with some TS data reported quarterly, as follows

```
quarter region value
2018T4    A      4
2018T3    A      2
2018T2    A      3
2018T1    A      9
2018T4    B      6
2018T3    B      2
2018T2    B      5
2018T1    B      8
2017T4    A      2
...
```

I want to aggregate the quarterly observations and average them to obtain an annual mean value for each year and region, as such

```
quarter region value
2018      A     4.5
2018      B     5.25
2017      A     2
...
```

What would be an appropriate approach to this?

Comment: `library(tidyverse)`  
`data %>% group_by(region, quarter) %>%mutate(value = mean(value))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can remove the quarter information from year and take `mean` by `year` and `region`.

```
aggregate(value~year+region, transform(df, year = sub('T.*', '', quarter)), mean)

#  year region value
#1 2017      A  2.00
#2 2018      A  4.50
#3 2018      B  5.25
```

Same using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(year = sub('T.*', '', quarter), region) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value))
```

Comment: God bless you. It was so simple, I was really struggling to realize how to make R interpret those 20XXTX as quarters. Sorry for such a noob question, just got started with R and am slowly getting familiar with it.